# $x = ((!y) && (y)) Вопрос с собеседования

Tags: php

Вопрос с собеседования:

> Возможно ли вычислить значение `$x` при любых известных значениях `$y`?
>
> $x = ((!$y) && ($y))
>
> Возможно ли, чтобы выражение вернуло `true`?
>
> Что будет, если вместо `$y` подставить массив?

Comment: Они, что, математиков набирают? Прикладная разработка далека от этих синтетических примеров на логику :)

Comment: @TotalPusher если вы не математик, то у вас и разработка далека. Остальные при необходимости используют в работе все инструменты и знания, которыми владеют.

Comment: @teran, зачем переходить на личности? `$x = ((!$y) && ($y))` в JS может вернуть true, не понимаю, зачем такие вопросы на собеседовании, в жизни такое не встречается. А если встречается, то пишут такое плохие разработчики.

Comment: @TotalPusher если вы про конкретно такой пример, кода, то такое, конечно, на практике сложно встретить. Я вообще про то, что логические выражения в прикладном коде весьма часты, и если у вас есть математический бэкграуд, то ты чаще этим пользуешься.

Comment: @teran, я даже не уверен, что второй вопрос на математику. Можно схитрить, и подставить в $y класс, который возвращает попеременно false, true. Но мне не удалось добиться такого поведения ни магией типа `__toString`, ни через SPL ArrayObject, ни чем-то еще. Но меня не покидает уверенность, что это можно сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Возможно. В любом случае сравнение *что-то* вернёт.
2. Операнды друг к другу обратны (т. е. если один вернёт `false`, то `!` обратит в `true`), а `&&` возвращает `true` только если оба вернут `true`, так что нет.
   Хотя может есть особые виды извращения/баги.
3. Пустой обратится в `false`, с элементами - в `true`. Из правила выше понятно что в `$x` вернётся только `false`.

Comment: Как оператор "и" может вернуть true, если заведомо известно, что один из двух операндов равен false?

Comment: @Diskyp, Вообще-то я так и сказал - он не вернёт `true`, ведь операнды обратны.

Comment: ой етить, точно, я неправильно сопоставил вопросы и ответы, дико извиняюсь, из за меня ещё и дизлайк влепили.

Comment: @Diskyp, Может и не из-за Вас. Переживу :)

Comment: Спасибо. Думал как раз может есть какой то конкретный случай когда вернет true. Теперь как то поспокойнее))

Comment: @serba, Вопрос на знание работы операторов, так что изучите внимательнее документацию по ним и вопросов не будет.

Comment: не удивлюсь, если при некотором строковом значении `$y` выражение `!$y` приведется к булевому типу и станет `true`, а `$y` будет при этом рассмотрено как непустая строка, и тоже вычислится как `true`

Comment: @teran, Ну правила просты - строка всегда будет `true` за исключением пары вариантов: `""` (пустая строка) и `"0"` (типа ноль как строка).

Answer (score 0):

> $x = ((!$y) && ($y));
>
> Возможно ли, чтобы выражение вернуло true?

Если не придираться, то возможно:

[image: php y.php]

```
<?php

declare(ticks=1);

$x = 0;

register_tick_function(function() use (&$x){
    $x = true;
}, true);

$y = false;
$x = (!$y && $y);

var_dump($x); // true
```

Comment: ну знаете,  таким же успехом перед `var_dump` просто можно было вставить строку `$x = true` :)

Comment: Я же говорил - было бы желание провернуть трюк...